# Parrallels 10 and Windows 10 keyboard typing incorrect characters

Tags: windows, parallels-desktop

When I type a double quotes on Parallels 10 with Windows 10 I see the following character.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Somehow Windows 10 set my language input to "English - United Kingdom" instead of "English - United States".

By removing everything besides "English - United States" under "Languages" in Control Panel it fixed the issue.